# Puppeteer: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded on Macos

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to get the https://www.cleverbot.com page content with puppeteer. But when I try:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {

    // Launches browser
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    console.log("browser opened");
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    console.log("page opened");

    // Go to cleverbot
    await page.goto("https://www.cleverbot.com/");
    console.log("cleverbot.com loaded");

})();
```

it always displays this error:

[image]

The website works when I use my browser application but not with puppeteer... Does anyone have any idea why?

OS: **Macos 10.12.6**
Puppeteer: **2.0.0**

Comment: Your code worked for me, maybe you are getting a real timeout.

Comment: Ok, I will try on another computer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your internet connection is slow.
Do this instead for disabling timeout.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer")

;(async () => {

    // Launches browser
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    console.log("browser opened")
    let [page] = await browser.pages()
    console.log("page opened")
    page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0)

    // Go to cleverbot
    await page.goto("https://www.cleverbot.com/", {timeout: 0, waitUntil: 'networkidle0'})
    console.log("cleverbot.com loaded")

})()
```

Comment: Hmm... the website takes one second to load in my browser. Speedtest displays 30mb/s so I don't think it's the problem. But I'll try with this